# Jquery rich text plugin not working for internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, rich-text-editor

I am trying to run jquery richtext editor in internet explorer but it is failing but in chrome it is working properly.

this is how i am calling the plugin and it is working fine for rest of the browser except IE

```
$(<%= TxtBoxBody.ClientID%>).richText();
```

but when written like this

```
$('#TxtBoxBody').richText();
```

I'm getting the proper output for IE but not for the other browsers

Comment: Wrap the string in quotes `$('<%= TxtBoxBody.ClientID%>')`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help your cause.

```js
$('[id$=TxtBoxBody]').richText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` to avoid `$('<%=TxtBoxBody.ClientID%>')` like this.

```
<asp:TextBox id="TxtBoxBody"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Now asp net stop changing id and you can get your ID static for all browser .Now all browser works with:

`$('#TxtBoxBody').richText();`